# Failing to install SUPER video converter

Tags: video, conversion

I am trying to install Super Video Converter ( `SUPER 2020 build 77`), but facing an error-

`Runtime Error`

`Cannot Import`

I need help

OS: Windows

I download from below link-

`https://www.filehorse.com/download-super/download/`

[image]

Comment: Version of Windows?

Comment: You might actually have got lucky - this app comes with a whole lot of bad news  https://www.google.ca/search?q=erightsoft+super+malware

Comment: While you are puzzling about the import error, it is busy encrypting your files. Now wait for the ransomware message.